# Select All option Not Workin Properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

i want to perform select all and deselect all action on a single check box click the below mention is my code

Html For SelectAll Checkbox

```
   <li>Check All
                  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAll" ng-click="checkAll()" id="myCheckbox"/>
                    </li>
```

Html For List Of Check box

```
<div class="column select">
<a class="checkbox" ng-click="item.isSelected=!(item.isSelected||false)" href="javascript:void(0);"></a>
</div>
```

Angular Js to select all Checkbox

```
 scope.checkAll = function () {

                if (scope.selectedAll=true)
                {

                    alert(1)
                    $('#myCheckbox').attr('checked', false)
                    angular.forEach(scope.contents, function (item) {
                        return item.isSelected = true;
                    });
                } else
                {                  
                    alert(2)
                    scope.selectedAll = true;
                    angular.forEach(scope.contents, function (item) {
                        item.isSelected = false;
                    });
                }



            };
```

Above mention is angular js to select all checkbox now  when i  select the select all  check box it works perfectly and select all the checkbox the only problem is when i deselect it, it does not perform any action i want to deselect all the selected checkbox while deselecting the main select all checkbox any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be your single equals sign in your if statement?

```
scope.selectedAll=true
```

this will allow you into the if statement block, but also assign scope.selectedAll to true. So you will never get a situation where you go into the else part of your statement... unless this is a typing mistake in  your post?